# Bigquery Send Alert When Table is Not updated

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to send alerts when Bigquery table was not updated more than 60 minutes , so i have written this query in **BQ query scheduler**

```
select 
  * 
from 
  (
    SELECT 
      TIMESTAMP_DIFF(
        current_timestamp(), 
        TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time), 
        MINUTE
      ) as minutes 
    FROM 
      `<dataset>.__TABLES__` 
    where 
      table_id = 'my_table'
  ) 
WHERE 
  IF(
    minutes < 60, 
    true, 
    ERROR(
      FORMAT(
        'too long since last update, %t mins ago ', 
        minutes
      )
    )
  );
```

I want to send this alert to multiple email address when this query fails, How i can do that currentl via BQ query scheduler the alert is send to only owner.

Comment: Can you follow this [Documnet](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transfer-run-notifications#email_notifications) for email notification when a transfer run fails. I hope this document will help you.